# Always seeing the "logged in menu"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I recently asked about why a peice of code wasn't working with regards to razor syntax, now I am back with the new question with the same piece of code:

```
        @if(Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated){
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service", "Index", "Service")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service Assignment", "Index", "ServiceAssignment")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Content Management", "Index", "Content")</li>
            </ul>                
        }else{
           <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Map", "Map", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        }
```

My question this time is:

Why is it if I am logged in **or** out, that I only see the menu, that you should only see if you are logged in?

That is I see the authenticated users menu regardless if I am logged in or not. Is there something I need to update in the controller?

Comment: Technically this is not the same piece of code.  The answerer changed your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity.aspx), `Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated`:

> Gets the WindowsIdentity type for the current user.

You most likely are using FormsAuthentication and would want to use ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx)) `Request.IsAuthenticated`.

> Gets a value indicating whether the request has been authenticated.

**EDIT**

I looked at code that we use to do this logic and we use the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))method to do this type of branching and not the Request property.  Perhaps this is where your issue lies.

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){...}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I still see the "I am logged in" menu. The example shows it in a method, Is this more controller based? sorry I am new to all this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this except I kept getting the error: `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpContext.User.get'` So I tried @using `System.Web.HttpContext.User;` and `User.get` with no avail.

Comment: Where is User.get coming from?  HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is what you should be using...

Comment: I am doing `@if(HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){}` and its got a red squiggly under httpcontext and user. hence the error message.

Comment: @TheWebs - my apologies, in the views, you need to use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated